# loop into array of object

Tags: javascript, react-native, loops

I have this array of obj

```
[{…}]
0: {name: "Test", _id: "601844119611f807bc14fe80", locations: Array(148), userId: "600cba4906ced9443c3d8419", __v: 0}
```

Inside of it i have the property locations , another array of obj that have this structure :

```
0:
locations: Array(148)
[0 … 99]
0:
coords: {…}
timestamp: 1612202687000
```

Inside of it i have the property coords , a simple obj that have a property speed :

```
coords:
accuracy: (...)
altitude: (...)
heading: (...)
latitude: (...)
longitude: (...)
speed: 0.15368179976940155
```

What I would like to obtain would be the average of all speeds starting from locations.
Now I have found a solution, but I don't really like it, I would like to find a cleaner solution. I enclose the solution that worked for me, but I'm sure there are infinitely better ways. Thanks in advance

```
const coords = track.locations.map((l) => {
    return l.coords;
  });
  

  const speed = coords.map((s) => {
    return s.speed;
  });


  const averageSpeed = speedConverter(
    speed.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / speed.length
  );
```

speedConverter is my simple function , it's not important .

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, you can do things more directly: `locations.reduce((p, { coords: { speed } }) => p + speed, 0) / locations.length`

Comment: Note, that it also works in the older style, without fancy destructuring: `locations.reduce((p, c) => p + c.coords.speed, 0) / locations.length` - it's not that clear, when destructuring is easier to read, and when not.